# Does DolphinDB have clause equivalent to LIMIT clause?

Tags: database, dolphindb

Usually (in MySQL) I use query like "select * from table limit 100" to peek the table, but I found it's not supported in DolphinDB. So is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

Use top clause in DolphinDB instead.

```
select top 100 * from table
```